# Mapping method to RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to do stuff with Spark (in Scala). I have a `Transformer` class that looks like this:

```
class Transformer(transformerParameters: TransformerParameters) {
  // Process the parameters

  def transform(element: String): String = {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
val originalRDD = sc.textFile("blah")
val transformer = new Transformer(parameters)
val transformedRDD = originalRDD.map(transformer.transform)
```

Assuming I don't want to or can't make the `Transformer` class serializable, and further assuming that `TransformerParameters` is in fact serializable, I've seen people suggest writing instead (or I may have misunderstood):

```
val transformedRDD = originalRDD.map(new Transformer(parameters).transform)
```

I'm fine with creating a new `Transformer` instance on each JVM of the cluster, but it looks like this creates a new `Transformer` for every line, which seems unnecessary and potentially very expensive. Is this actually what it does? Is there a way not to make a new instance for every line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could broadcast (implicitly or explicitly) an object that has a field for the parameters, as well as a transient field reference to a Transformer.

You have a method on this object that delegates to transform on the Transformer, but first does lazy initialisation of the Transformer (check to see if the Transformer reference is initialised, if not create one with the parameters, then call transform).

In the map method you then call wrapper.transform rather than Transformer.transform - this saves the object creation on each call, and works around the serialization problem as each task gets it's own wrapper instance and hence it's own Transformer that will get reused.

Comment: That makes sense. Is this a normal way to do things or am I trying to do something very unidiomatic?

Comment: I believe so, at least in Spark (and as someone that's coming to the table from a primarily Java background) - it's what I do in such situations anyway. There is most likely a more Scalarific way to do it but I've not yet discovered it!